# Are 'senders' required to have a paypal account when using Adaptive payments>Chained Payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Are 'senders' required to have or set up a PayPal account when using Adaptive payments>Chained Payments? It's not a problem for the receivers but for the senders, a lot of people just want to use their credit card to pay and don't wish to set up a PalPal account just to check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sender is not required to have a PayPal account when making Adaptive Chained Payments. Below is a screen shot of my recent test on their sandbox site for Adaptive payments -> Chained Payments .
[image]